# graphql single select query for all or few schema fields

Tags: graphql

I have a  graphql schema like bellow

```
const SellerjobtypeType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'Sellerjobtype',
  fields: () => ({
    id: { type: GraphQLString },
    sellerName: { type: GraphQLString },
    sellerAdd: { type: GraphQLString },
    status: { type: GraphQLString },
    requestRaiseTime: { type: GraphQLString },
    percent: { type: GraphQLString },
    runtime: { type: GraphQLString },
    jobid: { type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString) },
    specialinstructions: { type: GraphQLString }
  })
});
```

When I am writing graphql server code to fetch all SellerjobtypeType for a sellerName I have to create a resolver endpoint.

```
sellerjobtype: {
      type: SellerjobtypeType,
      args: { id: { type: GraphQLString}},
      resolve(parent, args) {
        return Sellerjobtype.findById(args.id);
      }
    }
```

This will search based on id only

Now I wanted to search by sellerName I created another endpoint

```
sellerjobtype2: {
  type: SellerjobtypeType,
  args: { sellerName: { type: GraphQLString}},
  resolve(parent, args) {
    return myObj.findByName(args.sellerName);
  }
}
```

If I have to search for some other field I create another endpoint.

Doesn't this defeat the graphql purpose of not having to create multiple endpoints. I think I am making a mistake. Please suggest how can I create  custom endpoint which can handle all search based on all or few of  the field in the SellerjobtypeType

Comment: you can create one query which will either resolve by id or name, like having an sql query where id = 'something' or name='something'. It's not really a GraphQL related problem, it's just giving you a schema language and a run time, we need to write the resolvers for the data. So it's all based on how you write your service and data model.

Comment: @pavan i meant in graphql query if you see we have the following line           
                                args: { sellerName: { type: GraphQLString}},                                                                        This means for every new set of argument i need to specify  all of them . Hence the question if we can specify all the arguments in 1 go of type schema